# Getting 'undefined' when fetching data from mongo database in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm making a worktime logger as an exercise. It should be able to show the user their earlier time entries. Fetching user data works fine, but when I try to get a log entry from an another table, I only get undefined. Nothing would show on the app either, but again, the user data shows fine.

Tried a few things but none of them would work the way I wanted. Here's the latest code:

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
      this.username = profile.user.username;
      console.log(this.username + " on ngOnInit");
      this.getLogs(this.username);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

// Pass the username on load to the function, fetches all the logs
  getLogs(username) {
    console.log(username + " in getLogs()");
    this.authService.getLog(username).subscribe(workhour => {
      this.log = workhour.log;
      console.log(workhour.log);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
// Get users data (username etc.)
     getProfile() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.loadToken();
        headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json());
      }
    
// Fetch all the logs for user from database
      getLog(username) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.loadToken();
        headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken)
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        console.log(username + " in auth.service.ts");
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/logs/get/' + username, {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json());
      }
```

I suspected the problem having something to do with `this.getLogs(this.username)` being inside `...getProfile().subscribe(...`. However, The console.log entries all show the username fine, but when it gets to `console.log(workhour.log)`, it would show 'undefined'. I tried also putting it in different points and changing the 'workhour.log' in the said console.log into 'this.log'.

Been scratching my head to this for a couple of weeks. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** Simply using `console.log(workhour)` did a huge improvement. Now I see all the entries from database like I wanted.

Comment: Are you sure the data is sent correctly from the backend?

Comment: Seems there would be 2 cases which one request is failed and the other response was there but failed loading. Have you done `console.log(workhour)`?

Comment: The wanted data shows properly when doing a GET request on Postman, so see the problem unlikely to be in backend. 

Using `console.log(workhour)` gives me ALL the entries, just as I wanted. Didn't think of that. Thanks a lot!